# Flex MX:HTML handling errors and loading problems

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a simple mx:html that load a page.. I'd like to show a popup when there is a problem loading the page...

How can I handle this event? I have not find anything useful on the web :(

Comment: I guess you are using AIR then, you could add the tag.

Comment: Yes I'm using Air... which tag?

Comment: I think you'll need to watch the document for the load event, then check the text for an error message.

Comment: thank you... I used a socketMonitor to check if the connection is available before loading the page into the mx:html, now I only had to check the http errors...

Comment: Do you mean javascript errors or HTTP status like 404 (not found)?

Comment: HTTP status, 404, 403, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mx:html is based on htmlloader, and unfortunately you cannot read HTTP headers using this object, so you cannot read the HTTP status. Several workarounds are:

a)use an urloader before the htmlloader and check the HTTP status

b)you can read the html page content with yourhtmlcontrol.htmlloader.window.document. If it's a known page you can detect if the page content corresponds with some status.

I think that a) is more reliable than b).

Comment: thank you... I used the option A, urlloader for checking the connection and the HTTP Status, then if HTTP_STATUS = 200, the urlloader load the page.. :)