# Is there an event I can listen for when HTMLLoader is assigned an invalid page?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm using the AIR HTML component and I'm trying to find an event for when the URL that is set returns a 404. I don't see any event to find this.

Example:

```
<mx:HTML id="html" 
         location="app:/thisPageDoesNotExist.html"
         complete="trace('complete')"
         locationChange="trace('locationChange')"/>
```

The complete event is never dispatched when the page does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer should be here: [Flex MX:HTML handling errors and loading problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567084/flex-mxhtml-handling-errors-and-loading-problems)